# JavaScript to WCF Service encryption

Tags: javascript, wcf, security, encryption

I am looking for a good way to encrypt data between a JavaScript package and a WCF Service.  I describe one solution at the bottom, but would like something better.  Is there a way to do this without purchasing a SSL certificate, I want the SSL data transfer, but don't need the CA?

**Background**

I have a WCF web service that many web app tools are going to connect to. All tools will be approved and registered with the service code before being able to access the service.  We are writing a basic JavaScript package for communication to the service for the tools to use.

Data going to the service needs to be encrypted and we can't trust that even other users of the same tool won't try to listen to data.

I don't want to have to purchase an SSL certificate and keep it valid, and I am hoping since I only allow certain tools access and they use my package, I can get around it.

**One solution I found, but don't think it is good enough**

Hard code a key on the Server given to the approved tools during development.  When each tool starts up, it creates a new key and sends it to the server for that user and session of the tool.  All data going back and forth will be done on this new key.
Problem - What if someone is listening when the tool first sends its encrypted new key, they could just get the hard coded from one of the tools and figure out the new key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very basics behind public-key encryption, is that you have a public key and a private key. You can offer your public key to anyone in the world, with it they can encrypt messages that only the holder of the private key can decrypt.

So you can have a method in your service which provides the public key. Your tools will request that public key, to encrypt the data and use that to exchange data with your service in a encrypted way.

But note I said "encrypted" not "secure", SSL goes beyond encryption of HTTP body data, it encrypts almost the whole connection.

It also proves identity. How the service will know that you is really you?

How will you identify that the message has not been intercepted and changed somewhere between you and your client? SSL also offers integrity protection.

I suggest you to do not reinvent the wheel, or if you do, really plan that hard because security is very important. "don't want to" is not a good reason to do not buy SSL ceritificates.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to reinvent the wheel, that is why I asking.  I would love to use SSL but I don't want to have to use a CA.  Since the tools are registered, and my JavaScript package will know the server is valid, I don't need the CA validation.